# Make test case for reusable mat table columns in jasmine

Tags: angular, angular-material, jasmine, angular-test

This is my parent TS

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Column } from '../../../../shared/molecules/table/column';
import {
  DataRecord,
  TransitReport,
} from '../../../organisms/transit-report-wrapper/transit-report.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transit-report',
  templateUrl: './transit-report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transit-report.component.scss'],
})
export class TransitReportComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() dataSource!: TransitReport;
  @Input()
  columns: Column[] = [
    {
      columnDef: 'overdueReviews',
      header: 'Overdue Reviews',
      cell: (element: DataRecord): string =>
        `${element.overdueReviews} clients`,
    },
    {
      columnDef: 'outstandingCovenantBreaches',
      header: 'Outstanding Covenant Breaches',
      cell: (element: DataRecord): string =>
        `${element.outstandingCovenantBreaches} clients`,
    },
    {
      columnDef: 'outstandingMarginingBreaches',
      header: 'Outstanding Margining Breaches',
      cell: (element: DataRecord): string =>
        `${element.outstandingMarginingBreaches} clients`,
    },
    {
      columnDef: 'periodStartDate',
      header: 'Period Start Date',
      cell: (element: DataRecord): string => `${element.periodStartDate}`,
    },
    {
      columnDef: 'periodEndDate',
      header: 'Period End Date',
      cell: (element: DataRecord): string => `${element.periodEndDate}`,
    },
  ];
  convertedArray: Array<DataRecord> = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.convertedArray.push(this.dataSource.data);
  }
}
```

This is the HTML template

```
 <section class="transitReport">
<app-table [dataSource]="convertedArray" [tableColumns]="columns" class="transitReportTable"></app-table>
</section>
```

In Istanbul red block should be covered for the test case coverage.

[image]

This is the spec.ts

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MockComponent } from 'ng2-mock-component';

import { TransitReportComponent } from './transit-report.component';

describe('TransitReportComponent', () => {
  let component: TransitReportComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TransitReportComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [
        TransitReportComponent,
        MockComponent({
          selector: 'app-table',
          inputs: ['dataSource', 'tableColumns'],
        }),
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TransitReportComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I don't know how to cover the "cell" function and "element" template statement in the parent test cases.
Before its showing these stats:
44.44% Statements 4/9
100% Branches 0/0
16.67% Functions 1/6
37.5% Lines 3/8
I want to make all of them 100 by writing the test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below, i have used dummy data. I have iterated over all items of the array, you can use loop if required. So basically we are testing cell() with mock data pass to return required string.

```
    it('should test all cells of column', () => {
    const element = {
      overdueReviews: 'overdueReviews',
      outstandingCovenantBreaches: 'outstandingCovenantBreaches',
      outstandingMarginingBreaches: 'outstandingMarginingBreaches',
      periodStartDate: 'periodStartDate',
      periodEndDate:'periodEndDate'
    };
    expect(component.columns[0].cell(element)).toBe('overdueReviews clients');
    expect(component.columns[1].cell(element)).toBe('outstandingCovenantBreaches clients');
    expect(component.columns[2].cell(element)).toBe('outstandingMarginingBreaches clients');
    expect(component.columns[3].cell(element)).toBe('periodStartDate');
    expect(component.columns[4].cell(element)).toBe('periodEndDate');

  });
```